# How to create two relationship between nodes in graph DB

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I am new to neo4j graph database. I was just playing with and tried different queries using cypher.

I have small question, Lets say I have *Person* and *Movie* Node. A *Person* acted and directed a same *Movie*. How can I create two relationships(say, *ACTED_IN*, *DIRECTED*) between **same** *Person* and *movie* node.

> (Person)-[ACTED_IN]->(Movie) and 
>   (Person)-[DIRECTED]->(Movie)

Is it possible to do it or I am missing something to understand? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MATCH (p:Person), (m:Movie) where p.name = 'Clint Eastwood' and m.name = 'Dirty Harry' CREATE (p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m);

MATCH (p:Person), (m:Movie) where p.name = 'Clint Eastwood' and m.name = 'Dirty Harry' CREATE (p)-[:DIRECTED]->(m);
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that you should perform two queries, you can perform multiple updates in a single query like this:

`MATCH (p:Person{name:'Clint Eastwood'}), (m:Movie{name:'Dirty Harry'})
  CREATE p-[:ACTED_IN]->m, p-[:DIRECTED]->m`